# Coffee helps to decrease weight

Tags: health

Many women dream to have a beautiful body shape. They find a lot of different ways to put on their weight and that is my source of question. I heard a little bit about the coffee that it can help losing weight. Is it true that coffee can decrease weight?

Comment: Maybe this question is more related to http://health.stackexchange.com/ or http://fitness.stackexchange.com/